# force whitespace between ')' and '{'

Tags: checkstyle

in our code we sometimes have this

```
public class Demo{
    public String value(){
        if (something){  
            while(true){
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm currently trying to configure my checkstyle configuration to force developers to have a space before '{':

```
public class Demo {
    public String value() {
        if (something) {  
            while(true) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I can't get it to work. Does anybody know the correct checkstyle configuration for this particular setup? I want to check this code as part of my gradle build

Comment: Off topics-not a programming question

Comment: Couldn't you just edit the templates for code generation in the first place?

Comment: What integrated development environment are you using? Eclipse, Intellij, ....

Comment: I run my checkstyle tasks using gradle. fixing code generation templates does not enforce this when running on CI.

Comment: Can't you like, ask in [a relevant chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/java) for questions like these...

Comment: @EJP Reviewing code changes which also contain formatting changes can be really hard to analyze (e.g. 2 Developers which use different formatting rules)

Comment: I think the module you need is `WhitespaceAround`. http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_whitespace.html#WhitespaceAround

Comment: Why off topic?! Of course this is related (directly) to programming. Editor and tool configuration are absolutely deemed on topic on SO.

Answer (score 3):

If you use eclipse you could have a look at "Window/Preferences/Java/Code Style/Formatter".
You can set almost everything.

For your problem :

[image: Here]

If you want use checkstyle you can go to "Window/Preferences/Checkstyle/New ...".
And doing some thing like that : 
[image: Here]

Comment: as mentioned in the question I'm using checkstyle for analyzing my code style